Does the earliest known use of an "average" occur after the invention of calculus?
When making a broader point about how humans find it difficult to think in statistical and probabilistic terms, Neil deGrasse Tyson said:

Do you realize the first time anyone took an average of numbers, and figured out that that was a good idea, was after calculus had been invented?

A previous question (History of the arithmetic mean) links a source with this quote:

By the mean of a thing I denote a point equally distant from either extreme, which is one and the same for everybody; by the mean relative to us, that amount which is neither too much nor too little, and this is not one and the same for everybody. For example, let 10 be many and 2 few; then one takes the mean with respect to the thing if one takes 6; since 10-6 = 6-2, and this is the mean according to arithmetical proportion [progression]. But we cannot arrive by this method at the mean relative to us. Suppose that 10 lb. of food is a large ration for anybody and 2 lb. a small one: it does not follow that a trainer will prescribe 6 lb., for perhaps even this will be a large portion, or a small one, for the particular athlete who is to receive it; it is a small portion for Milo, but a large one for a man just beginning to go in for athletics.

This is technically an arithmetic mean, but I'm not sure it's how most people would think of an "average". Is there a first known example of someone adding up numbers then dividing them by their count?

Any time a group of people has collected certain values, and then redistributed equally, they technically used the concept of average. I’m quite sure this happened quite often even in prehistorical times already. Are you interested in such (documented) occurrences? If not, what’s the minimal level of definition and/or intentionality you’re looking for?

Yes @Neinstein, that would be an example of what I'm looking for. I am interested in such documented occurrences.

The idea and practice of taking an average or mean is much older than the 16th century.
Ancient astronomers such as Claudius Ptolemy (2nd century AD) were already accustomed to separating the non-uniform true motions of astronomical bodies into two parts.
One part was a 'mean' or 'averaged' part of the motion or position, resulting from a fiction of uniform and average motion that was easy to calculate. The other part was a calculated 'equation', or correction, to supply the fluctuating difference from the average or mean motion or position that yields the 'true' non-uniform position or motion -- sometimes less, sometimes greater than the average -- of whatever object was concerned.
The average part of that, or mean motion, e.g. in a day, would typically be measured by reckoning the total motion using observations over a long time-period, and dividing by the time -- essentially putting together a large number of non-uniform portions of the aggregate motion, and taking the average.
Ptolemy's major work of astronomy and mathematics was the 'Almagest' of around 150 A.D.; and G J Toomer, its modern (1984) translator from ancient Greek into English, wrote of the Greek words associated with means, averages, uniformity and non-uniformity, for example:

"mean (μέσος)(mesos) can imply ‘of average length’ (as in ‘mean
synodic month’) or ‘uniform’ (as in ‘mean motion in longitude’)."

In the ancient Greek, 'uniform' can be rendered "`ομαλος" (homalos),
and 'non-uniform' can be rendered "ανώμαλος" (anomalos).
Reference: G J Toomer  (translation and annotations),  Ptolemy's Almagest, (London and New York, 1984), especially p.23.

(+1) In the third book of Mathematicae Collectiones, Pappus of Alexandria (4th century) distinguishes the arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means of two quantities. Relevant page in the 1588 edition. On the following pages he then lays out some kind of generalized theory of means.

Thanks @njuffa for the Pappus reference and the interesting pointer to content.  There's also a relatively recent (1933) translation of Pappus into French, at  (https://archive.org/details/PappusDAlexandrieEd.PaulVerEeckeLaCollectionMathmatique). Some may find that helpful if the Latin gets too much. (The French seems to be the only translation there is into a modern language.)

Thanks for the pointer to the French translation of Pappus. I read both Latin and French with much difficulty, and consequently I only eyeballed the content following the initial mention of arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic means, and I have not tried to grasp the details to truly understand it. But it seems that Pappus constructed a system of ten different means which are summarized in a table (book 3, p. 79 in the French translation)).

@njuffa as far as I can see Pappus only considers the case of means of three quantities and has a geometrical interest in them. I did not see any suggestion that he was interested in the statistical average but I may have missed it.

I know you're questioning the word "average" that he actually said, but I think  Neil deGrasse Tyson is closer to being correct if you consider as well the context in which he said it.
In 1654-1657, Pascal, de Fermat and Huygens all considered the gambling-related "Problem of Points": the solution to which required developing what we now call the "expected value". Likely by "average" Tyson means "expected value". I think that's a reasonable shorthand given the venue he's speaking in, and the fact he's setting up a remark about casinos. But of course for a word so ambiguous as "average" it leads to a radically untrue soundbite. The 1650s novelty was to think that the (weighted) average of all the possible outcomes of an uncompleted gambling game "was a good idea". It was already known that the average of a list of numbers was a good idea in other contexts.
I still can't quite square the dates, though. In 1654, Newton was 12, Leibniz was 8, and neither of them of course had done the work which is now credited to them under the name "calculus". There was proto-calculus before 1654: for example Kepler pretty much used integration about 50 years earlier. For that matter Archimedes solved the special case of the volume of a sphere using geometric methods loosely related to those of integral calculus, without having any general concept of calculus. But then, there was proto-probability theory earlier as well, so you might have to get into a hair-splitting contest to really figure out which "came first". Also, the order these problems were solved mathematically might not solely have to do with how "natural" the concepts are (as Tyson says), but also to accidents of what mathematicians considered worth studying.
The general point probably stands, though, that the development of an expected value to study gambling post-dates (for example) the development of an integral calculus to study planetary motion. And that the latter is something the general public usually considers quite mathematically-advanced and hard to understand. So maybe they should be wary also of just assuming the former is all pretty obvious and they can busk it on intuition: especially when their money is at risk!

Be sure to check njuffa's comment under the other answer, you may find it interesting!

This may be giving NDT too much credit. He's notoriously bad with history, even history of science and math. He drops little historical factoids like this all the time without really fact-checking them before he says them, and he's even argued with historians in the relevant fields when they fact-check him themselves.

@Idran I think it's still probably the "correct" answer, in that it's probably the vaguely-remembered fact that NDT was referencing. Wild to me that the expected value is so recent--it feels like the sort of thing that would absolutely be in ancient sources

Interesting point @steve. I didn't realize the possible importance of the follow up comment he made about Casinos (although he seems to be referring to the gamblers fallacy as he says "people say it's due. It's not due!" What is the relationship between that and the Problem of Points?). That being said, the dates still don't work, as you point out!

According to MacTutor, citing the Oxford English Dictionary

AVERAGE, according to the OED, appeared in English around 1500 originally in connection with maritime trade in the Mediterranean. The dictionary gives a list of successive meanings of the term, as follows:

The definition which is closest to the sense of average as the arithmetic mean is the fourth one quoted

(4) Equitable distribution of such expense, when shared by a group. (1598)

Of course that is just the use of the term and concept in English as it may have existed well before that in the ancient world.

Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. So the average (and the idea that it is useful) clearly predates calculus (1665-1684).

"Equitable distribution of such expense ... by a group". Perhaps once you have addition and division, it's inevitable that at some point you'll compute the average of something. You don't even have to be trying ;-)

The way I understand "equitable" in this sense is that if the total value of cargo (and ship perhaps) is 100 and the value of my portion of the cargo is 40, then the average I would be charged would be 40% of the total insurance premium, or of the cost of the voyage, etc. It also might mean that other considerations could cause the charge to vary from a simple proportional division. In this interpretation, it is not an example of what @papaki seeks.

@MichaelE2 Your interpretation would in modern language be a weighted average, a concept that is clearly more sophisticated that just an average where all weights are equal.

@MichaelE2, a friend pointed this out to me, I think you are correct. And even if all the weights are equal, is it really an average @quarague? After all, it's a lump sum being divided, not numbers being added together and then divided.
